# Choice probabilities with Frechet distributions that have different minimums

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, econometrics, choice-modeling

For two independent Frechet distributed variables that have the same shape parameter but different scale parameters: 
$$ F_i(x) = e^{-\psi_i x^{-\epsilon}}, i=1,2$$ 
The probability of one variable being larger than the other has a simple closed form solution:
$$ Pr(x_1 > x_2 )  = \frac{\psi_1}{\psi_1 + \psi_2}$$

I am trying to obtain a similar result for Frechet variables that have different minimum location parameters, with distribution functions

$$ F_i(x) = e^{-\psi_i (x-m_i)^{-\epsilon}}, i=1,2$$

The probability, in this case, can be obtained by calculating

$$ 
\begin{align}
Pr(x_1 > x_2 ) &= F_2(m_1) + \int_{max(m_1,m_2)}^{\infty} F_2(x) f_1(x) dx \\
&= F_2(m_1) + \int_{max(m_1,m_2)}^{\infty}  e^{-\psi_2 (x-m_2)^{-\epsilon}}  e^{-\psi_1 (x-m_1)^{-\epsilon}} \epsilon \psi_1 (x-m_1)^{-\epsilon-1} dx 
\end{align}
$$

But I haven't found a closed form solution for this integral. This [paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiryNv_0KHSAhWIKWMKHVZgDiUQFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ucl.ac.uk%2Feconomics%2Fnon-seminar%2Fconsumer_behaviour%2Fjorgen&usg=AFQjCNEJYUI1f6Yw9_jU5YoA-aqqwJWvYg&sig2=lBnIbkIWoO5nMhVM-eejuQ) suggests that to have closed form choice probabilities the distribution functions need to satisfy $F_1^a(x) = F_2^b(x)$ for some $a,b$ which the latter distributions don't satisfy, but I'm not sure if this is a necessary condition.